# SharePoint Foundation 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 - compatibility?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, database

I have to upgrade SharePoint Foundation 2010 databases SQL Server 2008 R2 to SP2.

If SharePoint Foundation 2010 is full compatibility with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.

Also check:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/45f3d039-3e98-4791-a9da-bcd80ad71835/sql-server-2008-r2-sp2-and-cu2-are-compatible-for-environment-sharepoint-server-2010-sp1

Comment: Did you use/test that configurations?

Comment: No, But as blogs and articles on msdn it is written that it is suppoerted. You may test it first on your test server.

Comment: I also found http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e693cc6-7d2e-4c18-b6bc-f169f90d4225/sql-server-2008-r2-sp2-for-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral